# Ruby & Rails - conditional count within block

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is a simple question but I can't figure out as I am new to rails.

My controller has a @neighborhoods variable which contains neighborhood records for each Business in the @businesses variable (each business has_one neighborhood)

In my view, I want to print out:

1. Each unique neighborhood name
2. How many of each unique neighborhood name (can be multiple since it is taken from the @businesses variable)

Currently I have:

```
<% @neighborhoods.uniq{|x| x.name}.each do |neighborhood| %>
   <p><%= neighborhood.name %></p>
   <%= @neighborhoods.where{name = neighborhood}.count %>
<% end %>
```

I know the above code is wrong, but it illustrates what I am trying to do. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Try validating from your model. `validates :neighborhood, :uniqueness => {:scope => :name}`

Comment: I Suppose it is `@neighborhoods.where{name = neighborhood}.count`

Comment: That’s a lot of logic for a view, try moving it to a model or service object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<% @neighborhoods.group_by(&:name).each do |name, neighbourhoods| %>
  <p><%= name %></p>
  <%= neighbourhoods.count %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got this error: both block arg and actual block given